# An umbrella term for property crimes without the use of violence

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there an umbrella term (ideally, a single word) for crimes of illegally taking possession of someone else's property “quietly”, not involving the use of violence, threats, or endangerment?

- So it should include pickpocketing, shoplifting, breaking & entering (if no one is present in or near the building who could be endangered or alarmed), embezzlement, fraud, stealing money in electronic form using illegal access to computer systems, forgery of money or documents representing ownership of property.
- But it should exclude robbery, extortion, taking hostages, vandalism (because it is destruction rather than taking possession), and crimes involving high-speed car chase (because it endangers people).

Comment: Maybe "larceny" - M-W: ": the unlawful taking of personal property with intent to deprive the rightful owner of it permanently"

Comment: "property crime" is a common phrase. Your list seems very arbitrary though, vandalism is often fixed with soap and water but burglary can cause lasting psychological scars.

Comment: I have heard a term that fits this concept quite well.  Sadly, I can't remember what it is.

Comment: Strange that you should include breaking & entering but exclude vandalism.

Comment: @WeatherVane The purpose of breaking & entering is not to damage a window or door, it is to get access into the building to steal some property (a broken window is just collateral damage). The purpose of vandalism is just to destroy some property in retaliation, intimidation, protest, mischief, etc.

Comment: I would have thought that breaking & entering constitutes "use of violence".

Comment: @StuartF I explicitly excluded burglary when victims or witnesses are present during the commission of the crime. The victim will discover that a window is broken and some property is missing later.

Comment: @WeatherVane I meant the use of violence toward people like victims or witnesses. Surely, breaking a window, or picking a lock on the door requires some use of force, but if there is no one present to see it, I do not think it can be called violence. Or maybe I misunderstand the exact scope of the term “violence”.

Comment: I would call it “stealing.” Robbery is not usually included in that umbrella

Comment: It's getting philosophical: ["If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest)

Comment: @WeatherVane No, I do not think it is philosophical. Some criminals consider it morally acceptable to deprive others of their property (e.g. because they believe other people are unfairly rich, or perhaps they have some noble purpose that requires money they do not have), but they try to avoid any open confrontation with victims, either because they are not prepared to go through such experience and related risks themselves, or do not want to subject others to it.

Comment: No, they avoid confrontation because it increases the chance of getting caught and/or hurt *themselves*.

Comment: Isn’t that called *white-collar crime*?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just "theft"? or "non-violent theft"?

Answer (score 0):

You typically hear of these types of crimes referred to as "non-violent crimes". You can call it "finessing" if you like. As Jack mentioned in the comment, one example of these crimes is larceny, although not all of these crimes can be called larceny.

Comment: I think that a “non-violent crime” is a much wider term than I need. It includes crimes not involving illegally taking possession of someone else's property, e.g. growing marijuana at home, jaywalking, trespassing, crossing a border without inspection, driving with an expired driver's license, ignoring a subpoena, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps “Adverse Possession” covers the spread here? I’m not sure, it might be more of a land type property inference, but maybe it will help?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The problem with *adverse possession* is that not many native speakers of English who neglected to get themselves a law degree would understand what it means.